# Resrving a table temporarily for some time

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am using oracle PL/SQL . I have a script that inserts few records into a table ,and inserts one field in an increasing order .

For example , if the table were student having fields as :name ,address and roll-number then it inserts first record, then inserts the second record with the value of roll-number incremented by 1 and so on .

This order of the field in the records being inserted is important to me . So , I was wondering is there any way by which I can ensure that for sometime this script is the only thing to be capable of inserting records into this table and the insertion of records by any other script or code or user is forbidden for sometime ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try LOCK TABLE command in Oracle. But you need to be very careful while using this command. Hope this helps.

```
LOCK TABLE <tablename> IN SHARE MODE NOWAIT;
```

There are various modes can be availed. Please look [LOCK TABLE](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/transactions/lock_table.php) for further information.